# If $N= \{q\in M:f(q)=const\}$ then $T_pN=\{v\in T_pM:(df)_pv=0\}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a n-dimensiona (real) smooth manifold and $f:M\to \mathbb R$ a smooth function such that $(df)_p\ne 0$ for all $p\in M$. It is well know that $N=\big\{q\in M:f(q)=const\big\}$ is a submanifold of $M$.

> Prove that the set $\Omega_p=\big\{v\in T_pM:(df)_pv=0\big\}$ coincides with $T_pN$ for all $p\in M$.

It is easy show that $T_pN\subset \Omega_p$, but I can not prove that $T_pN\supset \Omega_p$.

Maybe we need suppose that $M$ is also a riemannian manifold (?)

Comment: Since $T_pN$ and $\Omega_p$ (the kernel of the differential, which is a linear mapping) are vector spaces, you can maybe try to show (using rank-nullity theorem or such) that they have same dimension, and thus that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard result that if $f : M \to N$ is a [submersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)) and $q \in N$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}({q})$ is a submanifold of $M$ and $\dim f^{-1}({q}) = \dim M - \dim N$. In your case, $N = \Bbb R$, so $\dim N = n-1$ with $n = \dim M$. It follows that $\dim T_p N = n-1$.

On the other hand, we have [the first fundamental isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Modules) telling us that $\dfrac {T_p M} {\ker \ \Bbb d_p f} \simeq \text{range } \Bbb d_p f$. Since $\ker \Bbb d _p f = \Omega_p$ (be the definition of $\Omega_p$), and $\text{range } \Bbb d_p f = T_{f(p)} \Bbb R \simeq \Bbb R$ (because $\Bbb d_p f \ne 0$), it follows that $\dim \dfrac {T_p M} {\Omega_p} = \dim \Bbb R$, whence $\dim T_p M = \dim \Omega_p + \dim \Bbb R$, so that $\dim \Omega_p = n-1$.

Since you had already obtained $T_p N \subseteq \Omega_p$ and we have obtained $\dim T_p N = \dim \Omega_p$, it follows that $T_p N = \Omega_p$.